# What is the pixel size (wide) on the facebook interface before showing page ads and my message option

Tags: facebook

I've been looking for the pixel width of the facebook homepage, excluding the page ads and your profile options, such as `MESSAGES` and News feed.

I have tried searching for it, but my answer is not found. Please let me know if you have the answer. (And if you have facebook on max size on your browser, if that changes anything, but I mean like the full width of the full size web-browser.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know things like this, and you know your way around a graphics editing program, make a screen shot of the FB page, load it into your editor and measure in there.

These programs e.g. all show the size of the bounding rectangle if you make a rectangular selection of the item you want to measure.

This does not work if the objects in the web page size with your windows browser size, but even then you can often calculate a size by e.g. subtracting sizes of fixed elements from your browser window size.